# 3D frame stiffness matrix local to global

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, matrix-elements

I am working on a simple script to be able to solve frame structure using direct stiffness method.

I am having following stiffness matrix for 2 node frame element:
[image]

What is the correct way of transforming this local stiffnes matrix into global coordinates.

I have only found simplified truss 2d transformation matrices etc.

Thanks.

Comment: Start with a much smaller system and work out the transformation by hand. Then do it with a slightly larger system and do it by hand. Hopefully by then, the pattern will emerge.

Comment: You need to show us which axis is what, and what convention is used for the local to world transformation of individual vectors.

Answer (score 1):

The matrix you show displays twelve degrees of freedom for two nodes, so six degrees of freedom per node. Transferring this matrix to global coordinates is as if you are rotating the beam (beam length is already included in the matrix). Rotation matrix $R(\vec{\theta})$ can be used to rotate a force $\vec{F}$. You already apply force in global coordinates, which are the local coordinates rotated by $\vec{\theta}$, the displacements have to be rotated as well. You do this for each forcing vector: two moments and two moments of force, yielding the following matrix:

$$R_{total} = \begin{bmatrix} R & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & R & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & R & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 & R \end{bmatrix}$$

and thus your global stiffness matrix:

$$K = R_{total}K_{element}$$

Answer (score 0):

Each element has a transformation matrix of the form

$$ E_{6×6} = \begin{bmatrix} R_{3×3} &  [\vec{r}\times] R_{3×3} \\ 0_{3×3} & R_{3×3} \end{bmatrix} $$

where $R_{3×3}$ is the orientation matrix, and $[\vec{r}\times]$ is the 3×3 skew symmetric cross product operator of the element position $\vec{r}$ defined by: $$ \begin{pmatrix}x\\y\\z \end{pmatrix}\times = \begin{bmatrix}0&-z&y\\z&0&-x\\-y&x&0\end{bmatrix}$$
.

The cross terms exist because remote forces cause equipollent moments to appear.